# How to fetch 3 minute interval data using Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, where-clause

In database we have data every one minute like time as `2020-01-01 9:00:00, 2020-01-01 9:01:00`......we need to fetch data with in from and to date as 3 minute interval
for example we have time field in database `2020-01-01 9:00:00 to 2020-10-01 9:00:00`. I need to use the query to get 3 min interval of given from, to date the output should be

```
2020-01-01 9:00:00
2020-01-01 9:03:00
2020-01-01 9:06:00
```

if we give from date as `2020-01-01 9:00:00` and to date as `2020-01-01 9:07:00` and the interval is 3.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `timestamp_diff()` and arithmetics:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
        mydate >= '2020-01-01 9:00:00'
    and mydate <  '2020-01-01 9:07:00'
    and timestampdiff(second, mydate, '2020-01-01 9:00:00') % (60 * 3) = 0
```

This works by making sure that the difference, in seconds, between the starting date and the date on the current row is a multiple of 180 seconds (ie 3 minutes).

If not all records have `0` seconds, you can be a little lax on the second part and focus on the minutes with:

```
    and timestampdiff(minute, mydate, '2020-01-01 9:00:00') % * 3 = 0
```